# Kentico Get Current URL for Page Type Field/Dropdown/Component

Tags: url, macros, kentico

I'm trying to create a dynamic page type field, it should able to access correct "Settings" folder to capture the Data Item based on the root (Finance or Procurement):

[image]

[image]

Let's say the page type being used under **Finance**, the field should go to '**Finance**/Setting/(whatever)'.

What I have done is 'hardcode' the path:
[image]

[image]

I have tried CurrentDocument.DocumentAliasPath, GetDocumentUrl() and so on, it doesn't show anything on the dropdown.

Is there any way to directly get the "Root(Finance or Procurement)" or indirectly get (Chopped from URL, or get URL using GUID)?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In page type fields you can use `DocumentContext.EditedDocument` object to get current page and it's properties. So you can use the following property to get current node name [image]

Comment: Hi Anton, I tried this, but I found the value only appear if I logged in, it wasn't working if I access without login. I reconfirmed that if I hardcode the value it works fine for both login and without login.